# Design Researcher or UX researcher?

Tags: user-research, research

I noticed in linkedin last week that many people are referring themselves as "**Design researchers**" instead of "**UX researchers**".

I was researching and reading articles to see if there is any difference in those two practices and I didn't find out anything.

**Is there a difference or is it (again) a different label to call the same role?** Does anyone here knows?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a different label to call the same role.

Because for both jobs, research plays a big role in your mission.

Answer (score 2):

The UX research goes by different names - UX researcher, Design researcher, UX designer ( who also performs research in small organization), product researcher, product designer, etc. It all comes down to the size of the organization. In small organizations, a UX researcher or UX designer has to do everything from conducting research, empathy mapping and designing. However larger organization have different teams set-up for different roles such as UX designer, UI designer who takes care of UI elements, and then there is UX researcher whose main job is to do only research including usability studies. My suggestion will be to read the job responsibilites instead of concentrating on the job title. As by reading the job duties one can learn if the responsibilities lean towards research or design. Depending on your strength and interest you can apply for the position.